# Show insignificant zero

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I want, when I write a Number in a Cell, that the zeros are still visible. In a Google sheet.

e.g. when I write 1.050, or 1.0 or 1.2000 there should stay exactly that.
Not 1.05; 1; 1.2 or something like 1.0500; 1.0000; 1.2000.

I just want, that the Zeros where I write in the cell, should show and not be removed. 
Moreover, the cell type shall not be a String, because I want to sort the Data, after the Value from the Numbers.
I have tried to create a custom Format, but I am failed.

Now somebody, how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

- **add positions you need with a <kbd>.00</kbd> button:**

  [image]
- **also you can set up a custom format number `#,##0.0000`:**

  [image]

Comment: This I already know. The Problem is, that I write with a Python Script Automatically in the sheet, in more than 100 cells and I don't want to make this all by hand.

Comment: and I need in different cells a different number of insignificant zeros and bye every Update I also need maybe a different number of zeros in the same cell. So I have do this automatically

Comment: @Nogrod answer updated